# Hide DropDown list for ComboBox without losing focus

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have created a userform similar to a google search. I'd like the drop down to show/hide depending on how many letters are in value.

Like this..

```
If Len(ComboBox1.Value) > 4 Then
    ComboBox1.DropDown
Else
    'ComboBox.DroppedDown = False  (non-existent method)
End If
```

There are many versions of this question, most result in changing focus, but this should occur while the box is being typed in. I find it hard to believe it's not possible..

EDIT: Question pertains to hiding the list below, not the arrow to the side - as it is set to always hidden - the list should hide/unhide based on length of value.

Comment: Do you mean the down arrow?

Comment: FWIW that comment should say `(damn you, ActiveX!)` - the VBA language itself has nothing to do with how limited MSForms control customization is.

Comment: Good point!!  ^^ you are correct. No not the down arrow, the list that appears below

Comment: @EndUserAbuser have you resolved this please? I'm facing the same challenge?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get is this, but for some reason if you delete characters it doesn't update. Plus it only starts working once there are more than 5 characters! Edit - amended as per Mistella's comments.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If Len(Me.ComboBox1.Value) > 3 Then
    Me.ComboBox1.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenAlways
Else
    Me.ComboBox1.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenNever
End If

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me.ComboBox1
    .AddItem "A"
    .AddItem "B"
    .AddItem "C"
    .AddItem "D"
    .ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenNever
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The backspace and delete buttons can be observed in the `ComboBox1_KeyDown` event -- their effect doesn't roll on into the `_KeyPress` event. To update when a character is deleted, you'll have to duplicate the code from the `_KeyPress` to the `_KeyDown`  ---   Or just add the code to the `ComboBox1_Change` event...

Comment: Also, since the code is in the `_KeyPress` event, the `.Value` being looked at is **_before_** the update to the text.

Comment: @Mistella - thanks for the comments, the Change event appears to work just as well too.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, I've updated the question to specify that this is the drop down itself, not the arrow button

Comment: Have you tried the code? You should just see in effect a textbox until 4 characters and then the dropdown appears.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is still important for you, I've managed to avoid showing the dropdown by consequent disabling and enabling the control.

In my case I wanted the combobox to call another userform by click on the arrow with subsequent pasting the result into the texbox part of combo. I also was irritated by the dropdown appearing.

I'm not sure it will do you any help, as subsequent .SetFocus causes dropdown to appear again..., but just in case, following helped me:

```
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Enabled = False
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Enabled = True
```