# Hide Excel ActiveX ComboBox DropDown list

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, dropdown, activex

I am aware that this thread already exists:
[Hide DropDown list for ComboBox without losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262375/hide-dropdown-list-for-combobox-without-losing-focus)

But unfortunately, it is for a UserForm and isn't applying to my questions.

My situation is rather on a Worksheet like below:

[image]

In fact, to show that dropdown list, here is what I did:

```
shLedgerImport.CboAcctCode.DropDown  'This function shows the dropdown list
```

But **once it appears, I cannot hide it anymore**:

**---> I just want it to hide that dropdown list when I click on E2, of H5 or anywhere except E9 that is the ActiveCell.**

(In case the user displayed it by mistake and want it to hide, what they need to do? Escape key isn't working, Click elsewhere isn't working)

Thank you

Comment: I am assuming that you're using worksheet events to do so. I am [linking](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html) where they use a combobox, but the steps should be the same for yours. Basically trigger this on the Selection_Change event

Comment: But where is the line `shLedgerImport.CboAcctCode.DropDown`? In an event? Why E2 is different from the other mentioned cells? Is it the one triggering an event with has the code line in discussion? If yes, what event? If no, do you try telling that there is no connection between the `DropDown` action and current active cell?

Comment: @Sgdva: Wow, thank you so much, this is excellent documentation!

Comment: @FaneDuru: `shLedgerImport.CboAcctCode.DropDown` is in a Cell Double Click event. When I double-click a Cell, it is dropping down the list to be seen. And yes, the current active cell and the DropDown are connected, I'm still trying to figure out how to get the dropdown go directly to the row closer to the content of the active cell. :)